# how to create error event when tomcat application doesn't startup

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I use tomcat 7.0.23 and spring 3.0.5+. I want to generate event if application has started succeessfully or failed. I can generate successful event: I create bean `ProductPostInitializer implements InitializingBean` which depends on my service beans and if method afterPropertiesSet calls I generate successful event.

How to generate error event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html):

```
public class NotifyingContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        try {
            super.contextInitialized(event);
            //generate success event
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            //generate failure event
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in your `web.xml` instead of [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html):

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.NotifyingContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Note that your solution for generating success event is not completely safe. It generates event when `ProductPostInitializer` bean is successfully created, not the whole application/context. This means the event can be generated even if the context startup fails afterwards (e.g. beans depending on `ProductPostInitializer` fails to start).

Solution above solves this issue.